# AWS Lambda CLI or SDK to update test events from source control

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, aws-lambda

AWS Lambda console allows you to trigger your Functions with a test event.

[image]

You can name the test event and save it.

Question: Is it possible to save these test events via the CLI. I would like to store the JSON in version control and update them via the SDK or CLI for my pipeline.

[Improved Testing on the AWS Lambda Console](http://%20https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/improved-testing-on-the-aws-lambda-console/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly its not possible. The test events are **Console specific**. However, you can use SAM to get same or similar events as well, as described in [Generating sample event payloads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-generate-event.html).

Comment: Got the same response from AWS support too. Not possible to do this. Cheers for your answers chaps.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend considering the serverless framework: https://github.com/serverless/serverless

If you set up your deployment with its YAML config, not only is it significantly easier and less verbose than SAM, but it lets you invoke lambda with JSON events both locally and remotely:

```
sls invoke [local] --function <handler> --path <path_to_json_event_file>
```

As an alternative, you can use `--data` and pass a JSON string but the above would let you have the test events in version control.

See here: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/invoke/

Comment: I would recommend to anyone considering using the serverless framework to take a look at terraform first. Serverless uses CloudFormation which is awful, very buggy and slow. Terraform on the other hand uses an API to interact with AWS.